# How to set screensaver for Lock Screen of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, screensaver, lock-screen

Is it possible to set the screensaver for the Windows 8 Lock Screen? When it locks, it shows the time, notifications, and background image. Then turns of my monitor after the time specified in my power options. Could I have it go to a screensaver instead? (and then turn of my monitor after the time in power options)

I am fine editing a registry settings or system file. I want it to show the "Ribbons" screensaver.

Windows 8 Pro with Media Center x86
Dell Latitude D620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't lock it manually...
Configure screensaver as usual and enable option "Require password on wakeup"

This is how the configuration will behave:
After predefined time, screensaver will start.
Then some time(define by you) later, the monitor go off.
At any point of time after screensaver starts, if someone wakes up the screen, it will end up being lock screen.

I think this is what you need.

Now, if you are leaving your workstation and want to lock it, you could trigger the screensaver instead which will be equivalent to locking it. To trigger the screensaver, just create a shortcut to it.

OR

You can use a neat utility MonitorES that does pretty much what you want:
https://code.google.com/p/monitores/. It can automatically start the screensaver as soon as the screen is locked. It can also be run at startup.

Comment: I'm not sure about MonitorES, but I like your first idea. I am used to `Win` + `L`, so I'll just make a different shortcut, or find some way to make a top-left hot-corner (kind of like in OSX). Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help...

Comment: If you want some crazy stuff, try autohotkey...
You can go to as high nerd levels as having some predefined mouse gesture to invoke a command(screensaver in your case)..:D