# How to start screensaver without a user logging in?

Tags: windows-10, screensaver, lock-screen

I have a Windows 10 Pro machine. I need the screensaver to start after the machine is booted up WITHOUT ANYONE HAVING TO LOG IN. It seems that when I change the settings for the screensaver in Display Setting, the changes apply to my domain account, but don't carry over into the Windows Lock Screen once I am signed out. If I am signed out, the machine currently just shows a Windows lock screen wallpaper showing the time and date in the bottom left corner.

How do I set the screensaver to start with no one logged in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set screensaver for Lock Screen of Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/668091/how-to-set-screensaver-for-lock-screen-of-windows-8), [Run screensaver after idle time on lock screen](http://superuser.com/questions/1019016/run-screensaver-after-idle-time-on-lock-screen?rq=1&noredirect=1)

Comment: The answer on the other question is different in that the user is initially logged in.